# R language: pixmap scale and rotate?

Tags: r, pixmap

there 
What is the best way to rotate and scale a pixmap or rtiff object?

Perhaps I have missed the facilities, but it seems the pixmap and rtiff packages don't have these features.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer this question based on my own research, and provide some other information that could be useful in general.

A) Simple answer: Use EBImage.

The PDF documentation is very nice, and the API for my use cases is nice and easy .....

```
#Reading:

> f = readImage("C:/colorferet/dvd2/gray_feret_cd1/data/images/00001fa010_930831.tif")

#Scaling:

> f0.25 = resize(f,64, 96)

#Rotating:

>f2 = rotate(f,30)

#vectorifying.....


> v = c(f0.25)
```

B) Supplemental information:

B1) Yep.... Confirmed -- rtiff and pixmap don't support the desired functionality.
I will go with EBImage, unless other information comes up

B2) There is another package...Raster... which looks like it could work, however the as.matrix( ) and as.raster( ) do not seem to act in a symmetrical manner, so there are surprises and a learning curve there.